# How do I filter SQL Server traffic between app and DB servers using Wireshark?

Tags: sql-server, filter, wireshark

I'm trying to identify the source of some ill-timed connection resets. I'm trying to use Wireshark to capture the traffic that goes between the application server and database server. How do I set up a filter for this in Wireshark?

Answer (score 20):

Wireshark has display filters and capture filters.  The capture filter captures only certain packets, resulting in a small capture file.  Capture filters are set in Capture Options (ctrl-K).  An example to capture SQL Server traffic would be:

```
host <sql-server-ip> and port <sql-server-port>
```

A display filter is set in the toolbar.  A display filter does not reduce the size of the capture. You can change a display filter while the capture is running.  An example display filter:

```
 ip.addr == <sql-server-ip> && tcp.port == <sql-server-port>
```

The default SQL Server port is 1433.

Answer (score 4):

You can use only `tds` to identify the traffic between SQL Server's client and server, this fill filter a lot of noise packet.

Or you can append the `tds` with the `and` or `&&` operator after other filters if you want to filter more specific traffic.